# seems like web.py sessions are in app rather than on client

Tags: python, session, cookies, web.py

So the code below is more or less taken from http://webpy.org/cookbook/session

If I run the app it works as it should i.e. counter increments by one upon each refresh, however if I access the app in an incognito window or other web browser, the counter does not reset. To me it seems like the session doesn't initialize with count: 0 as it should. What is it that causes the new session to take the values of session in other client?

```
import web
web.config.debug = False
urls = (
    "/", "count",
    "/reset", "reset"
)
app = web.application(urls, locals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), 
{'count': 0})
session_data = session._initializer


class count:
    def GET(self):
        session_data['count'] += 1
        return str(session_data['count'])

class reset:
    def GET(self):
        session.kill()
        return ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Sessions should be stored on the client but when I execute this code it seems like it is on the server, which would imply that only one user can use the app and I have to rerun the app to reset the counter.

I haven't been able to solve this for almost a week now. Pleeease help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example has sessions being created from the initial `session` variable. For example, `session.count += 1` would add 1 to the current `session`'s `count`. In your code you change `session_data` for each user. The way the documentation demonstrates creating a session variable with an initializer is:

```
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'count': 0})
```

So, instead of doing `session_data['count'] += 1`, the documentation recommends doing `session['count'] += 1` or `session.count += 1`. You would also need to update the `return` line in your `Index`.

I tested and confirmed that this works for me.